# Add query parameters to social login authorisation URI with spring security

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, spring-social

I am curretly using spring security for Oauth2 login via social providers (google, facebook etc). The current setup is based heavily on the following tutorial: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-1/

i.e. login is initialised by hitting a REST endpoint: [https://example.com/oauth2/authorize/{registrationId}](https://example.com/oauth2/authorize/%7BregistrationId%7D) which, after storing information about the login session (state + final redirectUri) in a browser cookie, will redirect the client to the requested provider's authorisation URI.

SecurityConfig.java:

```
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.example.security.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    /*
      By default, Spring OAuth2 uses HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository to save
      the authorization request. But, since our service is stateless, we can't save it in
      the session. We'll save the request in a Base64 encoded cookie instead.
    */
    @Bean
    public HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository() {
        return new HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                    .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth2/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                    .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .authorizationEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                        .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                        .and()
                    .redirectionEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
                        .and()
                    .userInfoEndpoint()
                        .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                        .and()
                    .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler)
                    ;

        // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    public HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository getHttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository() {
        return httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;
    }

    public void setHttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository(
            HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository) {
        this.httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository = httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;
    }
}
```

In the case of Google authorisation, the following is set in application.properties:

```
#Social Providers OAuth2 settings
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.clientId=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.apps.googleusercontent.com
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.clientSecret=secret
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirectUri=https://example.com/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=email,profile
```

which produces the authorisationURI below:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount
    ?response_type=code
    &client_id=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.apps.googleusercontent.com
    &scope=email%20profile
    &state=zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
    &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback%2Fgoogle
    &service=lso
    &o2v=2
    &flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
```

I want to add an additional query parameter: `&prompt=select_account` but am unable to figure out how. I have tried adding the line below to application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.prompt=select_account
```

but this has not worked (same URI constructed as before) - I can't see any property available to set this particular parmaeter listed under: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html

Is there a way to append these query parameters via Spring security?